# Get values of :checked radio buttons in a <tr>, then create a new table with those elements

Tags: jquery, checked

I've got a table, each row has several radio buttons in them. You can only select one radio button per row.

When you've selected a button, the value of that radio button is shown in a sidebar

For example:

```
<tr>
    <td><input type="radio" value="red" name="colour" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="blue" name="colour" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="green" name="colour" checked="checked" /></td>
    <td><input type="radio" value="yellow" name="colour" /></td>
</tr>
```

And the sidebar shows this:

```
<div class="tr-01">
    you've selected <span>green</span>
</div>
```

Which makes me break this down into:

- 1) For each `<tr>`, create `<div class="tr-xx">`
- 2) Put value of `:checked` in the `tr-xx`  `<span>`
- 3) Change this option when checked & update the sidebar

Comment: you haven't wrapped content in td. that is invalid markup

Comment: And here is [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/amzo9tap/). Seems to work after adding `<td>`

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Yeah it's not accurate that section, it's more of a thats the basic structure to highlight what i'm looking to do. I've updated the code to reflect this now

Comment: @Regent This is what I had, but it just infinitely adds the options. I just need the current checked option. I've updated the question

Comment: @AndrewLazarus so you want to have in `.picked` last selected value instead of all?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus you actually state one idea in question header (creating a table), another one in question body (list of values of selected elements) and third one in comments (value of currently selected element). So which one you want to do?

Comment: Is this what you trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/jnqw7uuc/

Comment: @MelanciaUK Not at all, I need to keep them where they are still

Comment: @Regent I'll amend the question and remove my attempts so it's simpler.

Comment: @AndrewLazarus so if MelanciaUK fiddle (and [its bug-fixed version](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/jnqw7uuc/1/) updated by me) is not what you want, can it be that my [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/amzo9tap/2/) is what you are talking about?

Comment: @AndrewLazarus ok, I hope I finally understand what you want to do.

Comment: @Regent That is almost what I need, except for each row there should be another line, as each row is a different question, the new element reflects the answer chosen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, finally we came to this version.

- adding `<div class="tr-xx">` for all `tr` on `document.ready`.
- saving class name of created `div` for each `tr` (for easy access in future).
- on `input:checked` change we look at related `div` and updated value in its `span` to the one from `input`.

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Regent3000/amzo9tap/3/)

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $('.variations tr').each(function(index)
    {
        var trClassName = formTrClassName(index + 1);
        $(this).data("classname", trClassName);
        var currentSelected = $(this).find(':checked').val();
        var appendElement = '<div class="' + trClassName +
                '">you\'ve selected <span>' + currentSelected + '</span></div>';
        $("body").append(appendElement);
    });

    $('.variations input[type="radio"]').change(function()
    {
        if ($(this).is(':checked'))
        {
            var picked = $(this).val();
            var trClassName = $(this).closest('tr').data("classname");
            $('.' + trClassName + ' span').text(picked);
        };
    });
});

function formTrClassName(num)
{
    var result = "tr-";
    if (num < 10)
    {
        result += "0";
    }
    result += num;
    return result;
}
```